# How to realise logic of pivot table in R using Group By

Tags: r, group-by

I am newbie with RStudio and would like to solve the following problem:

I have a dataset that contains the following data:

| userID | year | month | type | category | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | yyyy | mm | string | string | string |

Now I would like to have a table in the end showing per User, per Year, per Month, per Type, per Category how much he/she spent (sum of price).

i have now tried it via group by, which does not give the desired result.

the desired output should look like a pivot table in excel:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5bgP.png)

Is there a way to cascade the grouping? Like stepping through the levels of grouping similar to what you have on a pivot table.

I really appreciate any help!

```
data_group <- data_merged %>%                              
   group_by(userID, year, month, type,category) %>%
   summarize(balance = sum(price)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could share a reproducible example data set using `dput`? Also, what do you mean by "cascade"? it may help if you also provide an expected output.

Comment: Try the function `mutate` instead of `summarize`

Comment: Desired result is unclear. Please illustrate with actual data. For example, what does `year_sum_price` mean without a `year` column? *All* years summed up? Similarly, *all* months? *All* types? etc.